# Formatting request URL in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have been searching for long time to make work using prettus/l5-repository but none of things that I tried worked.

My problem is that I need to format get request url like

> ?search=name:John Doe;email:john@gmail.com

when user click submit button.

I have tried to replace `request()->query->all()` to `"search"=>"name:John Doe;email:john@gmail.com"` but it did not work. I believe request's GET URL should be that format.

How to format request URL like that?

**Controller index()**

```
$paginator = $this->Repository->scopeQuery(function ($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
})->paginate($limit, ['*']);

$paginator->appends(request()->query->all()); //Append Url query
```

**Blade**

```
   <form method="GET" action="{{Request::fullUrl()}}">
        <div class="btn-group pull-left" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <a href="{{request()->url().'/create'}}" class="btn btn-success"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Create Case</a>
        </div>

        <div id="filterDropDown" class="btn-group col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropDownTitle">Filter</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:14px">
                <li value="All"><a  href="#">All Record</a></li>
                <li value="Waiting"><a  href="#">Waiting</a></li>
                <li value="Resolved"><a  href="#">Resolved</a></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="text" name="status" value="{{Request::get('search')}}"  style="visibility: hidden"/>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group col-md-7 pull-right">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="basic-url"
                   aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="{{Request::get('search')}}"
                   placeholder="Search by Title or Case number">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search are a string, then you need explode ";".

```
$search = explode(';', request()->query->get('search'));

$final_search = "search=";

foreach($search as $key => $value) {
    $final_search .= $value . ";";
}
```

then pass **$final_search** to your view

Comment: I can only access request()->query->get('search') after request has been made.

Comment: Then you can change request()->query->get('search') to request()->query->all()

Comment: You can access anything in request query after request has been made that is where problem comes

Comment: So I don't understand your first question, in your case can you explain URL initial and your final expect? maybe I can help, sorry for my wrong!

Comment: when it send request url query looks like this base_address.com?name=John Doe&email=john@gmail.com. However, I want  base_address.com?search"=>"name:John Doe;email:john@gmail.com