# How to set request url parameter in php blade or just php with pure html

Tags: php, http, laravel-5

I want to put something extra information which is dynamic on get request URL right after user click submit button and right before it sent request to server.

Basically, I want to hold request until  modify request URL right before it send to server.

I could not find any solution from any other site.. I tried to use jquery due to do that I described above ..

If anything is unclear please leave comment so that I can change

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be GET? You can add a hidden input in your form and it will be POST when you press the submit button.

In an answer because I can't put comments yet.

Ask questions in comments here, I will update answer accordingly

Comment: Yes its search form so it should be get and the reason why I need to do is that  get request url should be certain format. If I can use POST how can I modify it before send request

Comment: @user3882878 Could you put an example (code) of what you're describing in your original post?

Comment: You can find my sample code from here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995136/formatting-request-url-in-laravel-blade I could not get right answer so I changed my question and simplifiyed